# Qt OpengGL Shader Program fails

Tags: qt, opengl

I am trying to write a modern OpenGL (programmable pipeline) program using Qt SDK .Qt OpenGL examples show only the fixed pipeline implementation.The documentation on how to initialize Shader Program is very poor.This is the best example on how to setup a shader program and load shaders they have:http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qglshaderprogram.html#details 
This is not very descriptive as one can see.
I tried to follow this doc and cann't get the Shader program working .Getting segmentation error when the program tries to assign attributes to the shaders.I think the problem is that I access the context in the wrong way.But I can't find any reference on how to setup or retrieve the rendering context.My code goes like this:

```
static GLfloat const triangleVertices[] = {
    60.0f,  10.0f,  0.0f,
    110.0f, 110.0f, 0.0f,
    10.0f,  110.0f, 0.0f
};

QColor color(0, 255, 0, 255);
int vertexLocation =0;
int matrixLocation =0;
int colorLocation =0;
QGLShaderProgram *pprogram=0;
void OpenGLWrapper::initShaderProgram(){
    QGLContext context(QGLFormat::defaultFormat());

    QGLShaderProgram program(context.currentContext());
    pprogram=&program;
    program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader::Vertex,
     "attribute highp vec4 vertex;\n"
     "attribute mediump mat4 matrix;\n"
     "void main(void)\n"
     "{\n"
     "   gl_Position = matrix * vertex;\n"
     "}");
     program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader::Fragment,
     "uniform mediump vec4 color;\n"
     "void main(void)\n"
     "{\n"
     "   gl_FragColor = color;\n"
     "}");
     program.link();
     program.bind();

vertexLocation= pprogram->attributeLocation("vertex");
matrixLocation= pprogram->attributeLocation("matrix");
colorLocation=  pprogram->uniformLocation("color");
}
```

And here is the rendering loop:

```
void OpenGLWrapper::paintGL()
{
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


     QMatrix4x4 pmvMatrix;
     pmvMatrix.ortho(rect());

    pprogram->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
    pprogram->setAttributeArray(vertexLocation, triangleVertices, 3);
    pprogram->setUniformValue(matrixLocation, pmvMatrix);
    pprogram->setUniformValue(colorLocation, color);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    pprogram->disableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
}
```

Anybody has can help with this setup? Thanks a lot .

Comment: May it just be your `pprogram` pointer not set correctly to point to the program? And your `matrix` should not be an attribute, but a uniform (that's also the way you try to set its data in the rendering function).

Comment: Do the shaders even compile and link? Do `addShader...` and `link` return true? If not, check the info log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a local `program` variable and let your `pprogram` pointer point to its address. But when `initShaderProgram` returns, the local `program`'s lifetime ends and you pprogram points to garbage, therefore the segfault when you try to use it. You should rather create the program dynamically and let Qt handle the memory management:

```
pprogram = new QGLShaderProgram(context.currentContext(), this);
```

This assumes `OpenGLWrapper` derives somewhoe from `QObject`, if not, then you need to delete the program in its destructor manually (or use some smart pointer, or whatever).

Otherwise your initialization code looks quite reasonable. Your matrix variable should be a uniform and not an attribute, but I'm willing to classfiy this as a typo. You should also not `bind` the program for the whole lifetime, as this is equivalent to a call to `glUseProgram`. You should rather use `bind` (and `release`, which does `glUseProgram(0)`) in your render routine.

Comment: Yes that was exactly the problem.I removed the pointer totally and work with the "program" variable directly.Now I don't have any compiler errors.But I am having the empty viewport.Guess I need to check the uniform and attribute assignment routine.Also I agree with @cbamber85 ;besides poor docs on OpenGL in Qt the GTGL seems somehow restricting.So I will probably try to put the original GLEW lib running in a widget.Thanks .

Comment: @Michael I don't have problems with the Qt GL objects for simple programs. And like I said, in the shader and initialization routine your `matrix` variable is an attribute and in the render routine you said it as uniform.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the Qt wrappers for OpenGL objects are rather poor and limited, I just made a thin-wrapper for straight OpenGL objects (made cross-platform and easy via GLEW), and made the usual OpenGL calls in QGLWidget.  It worked no problem, after struggling for awhile with Qt's equivalents.

Comment: cbamber85 ,could you share an example of such a wrapper please ?

Comment: Afraid not, it is commercial IP, but to give an idea: I used the QSharedData class as a base for VBO/TBO/etc. memory management, and then created wrapper methods for uploading generic data to BOs coupled with template specialisations for uploading Eigen and Qt types.  It's nothing fancy, but just enough to simplify the most common tasks, and provide memory management.